# Get list of active plugins in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Is there a way to programmatically get the list of active plugins in Eclipse?

I know `BundleContext` class has a `getBundles()` method that returns all installed bundles but I need a list of just the active ones.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bundle::getState()` returns the current state of a bundle. Possible values are `UNINSTALLED`, `INSTALLED`, `RESOLVED`, `STARTING`, `STOPPING` and `ACTIVE`.

To get all active bundles, filter the list of bundles returned by `BundleContext::getBundles()` to include only bundles with state == `ACTIVE`.